# How to retrieve categories links in Python scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a complete beginner and trying to scrape articles from a website but stuck. I am trying to get categories links and then go into each category and scrape articles. What am I doing wrong?

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = "https://readlightnovel.org/"

#Getting HTML page

r = get(site, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"})
html_content = r.content

#Parsing HTML

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

#Getting all categories from the page

category = soup.findAll(class_="search-by-genre")
for link in category:
   #print(link.get("href"))
   print(link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this to look for links that have forward slash + category + forward slash + some text:

```
import re # regular expression 

for link in soup.find_all(href=re.compile(r'/category/\w+$')): 
    print(link.text)
```

Result:

```
In [15]: for link in soup.find_all(href=re.compile(r'/category/\w+$')): 
    ...:     print(link.text) 
    ...: 
    ...: 
Action
Adventure
Celebrity
# and the list goes on...
```